# Why it is not positioned in relation to its container?

Tags: css

I'm triying to position a point inside a circle to practice CSS position, so I declared `.circle` with `position: relative` and inside the point with `position: absolute`. But I get the point positionated in relation to the `body`.

```css
.circle {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.point {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="point"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: where do you want this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.point` **IS** relative to the `.circle` and not body

My suspicion is that you think that `.circle` for browser is circle too but in fact it is rectangle and only presented to you as circle because of `border-radius` property. It can be seen when you insect this element.
Blue rectangle is your `.circle` element and `.point` is positioned relative to it just like you told it to.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its working right. If you put `position: relative` in `.circle` the position, of point will be relative to `circle` container.
See Modified Example of your code below. I have set point's position (left and top) to `100%`, and removed `border-radius`. See the point is positioned at bottom right corner of square.

```html
<style>
.circle{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}
.point{
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:100%;
    background-color: black;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius:50%;
}
</style>

<div class="circle">
    <div class="point"></div>
</div>
```

---

Now, see the position of point, when you remove `position: relative` from `.circle`

```html
<style>
.circle{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.point{
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:100%;
    background-color: black;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius:50%;
}
</style>

<div class="circle">
    <div class="point"></div>
</div>
```